# Spring STS pivotal localhost working but ip does not

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localhost, ip-address

I have a spring sts project and I run it on the server(pivotal) [image]

I can access the app using http://localhost:8080/webapp
but i cant access it using http://ipaddress:8080/webapp
and its on the same machine.Ideally the if u put ip address in place of localhost it should work .I guess some change needs to be done on the server files but dont know what change.Also its a MAC OS .Below is my service.xml connector string

```
   <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="${bio.http.port}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
```

Comment: Which ip address did you use?

Comment: IP address of my machine .Your web app can be accessed by other computers on the same lan using your ip address

Comment: Looks like a network related problem. Is your firewall blocking port 8080 for incoming requests?

Comment: no this cant be the issue ,issue may be with the server.xml file

Comment: Did you find a solution?